How to improve my 2D manga-art skill until meets industry standard? Anyone help me to find where is the weakness?
Greeting everyone,
I have been using this Stack Exchange for so many years, I trust this site for a long time. Every time friendly buddies from this site helps me a lot.
I have a question about I had drew a comic for a indie, but I feel weird about my manga-style comic art. Here the Link to "Butou Learning Ippa" Comic here. to see my drawing of comic there. See Indie's Instagram, My manga-style comic cover art inside of instagram feel weird too.
I feel bad about my digital drawing feel weird, but I can't see the weirdness of my drawing. The character, colors, background, everything weird. Can someone help me see the weakness, thank you.
My buddies felt strange about my art too, but they cannot help me to explain where is the weakness that make it weird. I think I better ask here. Is the solid wrong, the lighting & shading wrong, or the colors wrong, or more mistakes?
Actually I want to ask about how to improve 2D digital manga-art until meets industry standard? Start from correction of weakness.
Please, thank you.

Any criticize or something references/comment/explanation about manga art or 2D art or any art can help me out?

Hi Red, I think this question is too broad and opinion-based to be on-topic here. You can always ask such questions in the chat (but please be very patient, because it's very quiet there :).

Thank for your given comment, Joachim. I don't know where is the chat. I just familiar here.

Sorry, I intended to link to it. Here you go: [chat].

Thank you, Joachim. In the other hand, Any answer? Maybe the character design look weird or lack of solid drawing?

So what is it specifically that you do not like about the work? That sample looks pretty decent to me.
Only advice is to be more experimental. There is a lot of manga out there and a lot more people like you trying to get in, you need to do something in your work that will make it stand out.

Thank you, rebusB

np op; best of luck. going to vote to close since there is still no answer and not likely to be as is opinion based (with a touch of spam). cheers!
